# Dell XPS 15 9560 NVidia not correctly turned off when Intel graphics selected (Large Battery consumption even on Intel HD Graphics)

Tags: nvidia, 18.04, battery

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 on my XPS 15 9560 4K model. I get a huge battery cnsumption on powertop (>25 W) when running on Intel HD graphics. When running on NVidia (> 40 W). I only have 3-4 terminals and some Chrome tabs open.

I am guessing that the problem is the NVidia GPU is not shut down completely on Intel session as `nvidia-smi` gives the regular Nvidia output.

I installed the NVidia drivers from the Ubuntu ppa:repository.

System specs:

-Model: Dell XPS 15 9560 4K (Dual-boot with Windows 10)
-CPU: Intel® Core™ i7-7700HQ CPU @ 2.80GHz × 8 
-RAM: 16GN
-Integrated graphics: Intel® HD Graphics 630 (Kaby Lake GT2)
-NVidia GPU: GTX 1050 4GB GDDR5

Comment: What about your CPU usage?

Comment: When logged into an Intel session does this produce any results? `lsmod | grep nvidia`

Comment: after another clean installation the NVidia GPU appears to be properly turned off. However power consumption is a bit reduced but still high (around 20W) with tlp running.